# Why are these Knockout subscriptions notifying an object that shouldn't have subscriptions at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Check it out here:[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jk3gt5rk/5/)

Here's the html:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" ></script>

<div id="first">
<button data-bind="click: toggleColumn">Click me!</button>
</div>
<ul id="list_test">
    <!-- ko foreach: list -->
    <li data-bind="text: $data.ColName"></li>
    <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

Here's the javascript:

```
function ViewModel(){
    var self = this;
    self.showColumn = ko.observable(true);
    self.toggleColumn = function(){
        self.showColumn(!self.showColumn());
    };

    self.ListOfObjects = [
        {ColName: 'test1', visible: self.showColumn},
        {ColName: 'test2'},
        {ColName: 'test3', visible: self.showColumn},
        {ColName: 'test4'},
        {ColName: 'test5'},
    ];

};

function TestViewModel(params){
    var self = this;
    self.list = ko.observableArray();
    for(var i = 0; i < params.length; i++){
        var obj = params[i];
        if(!obj.visible){
            //obj.visible = ko.observable(true);
        }

        if(obj.visible){
            obj.visible.subscribe(function(){
                    var elements = $('li');
                    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
                        if($(elements[i]).text() == obj.ColName){
                            $(elements[i]).hide();
                        }
                    }
                });
        }

        self.list.push(obj);
   }
}

function initViewModel(){

    var mod = new ViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(new TestViewModel(mod.ListOfObjects),document.getElementById("list_test"));
    ko.applyBindings(mod,  document.getElementById("first"));


}

initViewModel();
```

So my issue is this. Why is it that when you click the button, that the 'test5' list item gets hidden and not the two subscribed objects (test1 and test3)? It seems to always default to hiding the end of the list.

I've done this with my actual code, since the JSFiddle was just barebone replication of the error, and I examined everything through Chrome's console / debugger.

Within the subscribe call, the obj.visible property when compared to the showColumn variable are not the same instance. If you getSubscriptionsCount on that obj.visible inside the subscribe call you get only 1 subscription which it should never have gotten in the first place because it never should have been defined. If you do it on the 'test1' and 'test3' visible properties you get 2 subscriptions (as expected) and they are references to the same instance as the ViewModel.showColumn.

Still within the subscribe call, if you check the value of obj, you'll get

```
{ColName: 'test5', visible: /*some knockout obj*/}
```

It never should have called subscribe from 'test5'. It should have called from 'test1' and 'test3'.

Now, how is it that obj.visible.subscribe is notified from 'item5' when the 'item5' object never received a reference to ViewModel.showColumns? How is it even possible that visible was defined for 'item5'?

To me, what it looks like is that a subscribe on a different ko.observable object is notifying a subscribe on a completely different (non-existent even) ko.observable. I'm pretty sure that shouldn't be happening...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a classic "closure" bug. Your `obj` variable is changing during the life of the `for` loop, and the last value it holds points to "test5". The event handler function uses that same variable, so when the event is fired, it looks for "test5" and hides that. You can solve that with standard closure & IIFE.

Here's the important code:

```
if(obj.visible){
  (function (obj) {
    obj.visible.subscribe(function(){
      var elements = $('li');
      for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
        if($(elements[i]).text() == obj.ColName){
          $(elements[i]).hide();
        }
      }
    });
  })(obj);
}
```

Here's a fixed [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jk3gt5rk/8/).

Comment: That completely fixed it. Thank you. Can you explain why that works? I don't completely understand it and I would like to stick it in my brain somewhere.

Comment: It's a bit too long for comments, and there's a wealth of good explanations of this on the web. Google: javascript closure